# Can my thesis LaTeX source files contents be under GPL v3?

Tags: licensing, gpl, license-compatibility, multi-licensing, lppl

I want to release all the LaTeX source files (*.tex), when I publish my thesis. I do 
not want to just release the PDF. So everybody can build my thesis with a LaTeX compiler from its source code. Can my thesis source files contents be under GPL v3? Or they need to be under LPPL?

Can I use a template with the license LPPL license?

```
%% abtex2-modelo-trabalho-academico.tex, v-1.9.6 laurocesar
%% Copyright 2012-2016 by abnTeX2 group at http://www.abntex.net.br/ 
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%% 
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is the abnTeX2 team, led
%% by Lauro César Araujo. Further information are available on 
%% http://www.abntex.net.br/
%%
%% This work consists of the files abntex2-modelo-trabalho-academico.tex,
%% abntex2-modelo-include-comandos and abntex2-modelo-references.bib
%%
```

---

Related questions:

1. [Is a PDF output from a LaTeX document, a “derived work” from the LPPL standard packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82713/is-a-pdf-output-from-a-latex-document-a-derived-work-from-the-lppl-standard-p)
2. [The GPL and LaTeX packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69007/the-gpl-and-latex-packages)
3. [License in LaTeX document, packages and answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82300/license-in-latex-document-packages-and-answers)
4. [How can I license my .tex files for open source?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179370/how-can-i-license-my-tex-files-for-open-source)
5. [Can I license my package under Creative Commons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163128/can-i-license-my-package-under-creative-commons)
6. [What license for releasing LaTeX templates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/what-license-for-releasing-latex-templates)
7. https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLOtherThanSoftware
8. [Can my closed-source software load GPL v3 data?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/can-my-closed-source-software-load-gpl-v3-data)
9. [Can I sell my project using GNU GPL v3?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4876/can-i-sell-my-project-using-gnu-gpl-v3)
10. [Am I forced to release my project under GPL, even though no GPL source is included?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/am-i-forced-to-release-my-project-under-gpl-even-though-no-gpl-source-is-includ)
11. [Can my GPL v3 software load unamed licensed libraries?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4330/can-my-gpl-v3-software-load-unamed-licensed-libraries)
12. [GPL-Licensed LaTeX template - implications for resulting work?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/gpl-licensed-latex-template-implications-for-resulting-work)
13. [Can I sell my primitive material which is intended to be processed in a factory software under GPL?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/can-i-sell-my-primitive-material-which-is-intended-to-be-processed-in-a-factory)
14. [Can I use GPL v3 for source code and CC BY-SA v3 for comments?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/can-i-use-gpl-v3-for-source-code-and-cc-by-sa-v3-for-comments)
15. [Must author's name be included in GNU GPL v3?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/must-authors-name-be-included-in-gnu-gpl-v3)
16. [If I'm using a GPL 3 library in my project, can I license my project under MIT license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/if-im-using-a-gpl-3-library-in-my-project-can-i-license-my-project-under-mit-l)
17. [GPL V3 with OpenSSL Exception](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/gpl-v3-with-openssl-exception)
18. [Can I distribute a BSD code with GPL v3 binaries?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/can-i-distribute-a-bsd-code-with-gpl-v3-binaries)
19. [What restrictions can I place on a device whose software is licensed using GPL v3?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/165/what-restrictions-can-i-place-on-a-device-whose-software-is-licensed-using-gpl-v)
20. [Can I distribute a BSD code with GPL v3 binaries?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/can-i-distribute-a-bsd-code-with-gpl-v3-binaries)
21. [What restrictions can I place on a device whose software is licensed using GPL v3?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/165/what-restrictions-can-i-place-on-a-device-whose-software-is-licensed-using-gpl-v)
22. [Can an interpreted program be under any license without restricted by its GPL'ed run-time environment?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4934/can-an-interpreted-program-be-under-any-license-without-restricted-by-its-gpled)
23. [Does GPL v3 compel the author to provide source?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4321/does-gpl-v3-compel-the-author-to-provide-source)
24. [Using a GPL V3 library in a Android app published on Google Play, do I need to release the application's source code?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4840/using-a-gpl-v3-library-in-a-android-app-published-on-google-play-do-i-need-to-r)
25. [Is the text in my open source project under the GPL?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/is-the-text-in-my-open-source-project-under-the-gpl)
26. [Need sellable license-text for "commercial use" of GPL v3 software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/need-sellable-license-text-for-commercial-use-of-gpl-v3-software)
27. [Can I redistribute BSD software under GPL with no changes?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/323/can-i-redistribute-bsd-software-under-gpl-with-no-changes)
28. [Can I publish my iOS app store app code to GitHub under MIT/GPL](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5657/can-i-publish-my-ios-app-store-app-code-to-github-under-mit-gpl)

Comment: Your question is at least an impressive link collection...

Comment: Hey, which license did you go with for your thesis? I think my recent question here relates to your question pretty closely (at least in terms of the domain of practices that it is referencing to), linking it here in case you (or someone else who comes across this question) know(s) a good answer: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10578/a-non-bloated-license-for-documentation-with-the-benefits-of-gpl

Answer (score 3):

You can release the `.tex` files that you authored using whatever license you like.

The LPPL license covers the LaTeX project itself, such as the compiler. If you do not distribute that, you don't need to follow its license.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the thesis may not be legally yours, e.g. here in Chile by law anything somebody creates as part of the study work is the property of the school. Or you might be required to assign copyright to the school to graduate.